# Why is IsReadOnly listed as a non-public member?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, icollection

I'm looking at an instance of ICollection called pxe in the VS Watch window.
I understand that the Raw View is meant to show the object without anything extra added.
The property IsReadOnly is a member of the ICollection interface and is public by default.
Why is it listed in the Non-public members in the Watch window?

[image]

Comment: Yeah coz it's totally infeasible that an IDE could ever have a bug.

Comment: Also no mention of explicit/implicit implementations ever involving non public members in that article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadonlyCollection<T>` implements both `IList` and `ICollection<T>` and both interfaces contains `IsReadOnly` property. `ReadonlyCollection<T>` implements this property explicitly, so you cannot access it without casting `ReadonlyCollection<T>` to  `IList` or `ICollection<T>`, and so visual studio treat it as non-public member